# Cannot lookup EJB bean from remote server

Tags: ssl, jboss7.x, jndi

I have Jboss 7 server and SSL is enabled for remote connection and JNDI property as below

```
java.naming.security.principal=admin, server=10.10.10.10
java.naming.security.credentials=1111
java.naming.provider.url=remote://10.10.10.10:4447 
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT=false 
jboss.naming.client.remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=true
jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_STARTTLS=true
```

If the client and server has the same IP, the lookup is successfully. However, if I try to loop up from other server that client and server is not the same, it's not failed.

I try to enable debug log of SSL and see some exception:

```
    !ENTRY com.test.my.client.fwk 0 0 2014-11-21 15:04:49.648
!MESSAGE (Timezone is ICT.)  ;6340; org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore logged : "Failed to connect to server remote://192.168.95.111:4447:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation failed with status WAITING
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.IoFutureHelper.get(IoFutureHelper.java:89)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.failOverSequence(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:193)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.namingStore(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:144)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.namingOperation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:125)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.lookup(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:241)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:79)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:83)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)

!MESSAGE (Timezone is ICT.)  ;6340; org.jboss.remoting.remote.client logged : "Client authentication failed for mechanism JBOSS-LOCAL-USER: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Failed to read server challenge [Caused by java.io.FileNotFoundException: \var\opt\ams\local \tmp\auth\local3549659832926743393.challenge (The system cannot find the path specified)]" 

!ENTRY com.test.my.client.fwk 0 0 2014-11-21 15:04:50.497
!MESSAGE (Timezone is ICT.)  ;6340; org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection logged : "Connection error detail:
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
    at org.xnio.nio.AbstractNioStreamChannel.read(AbstractNioStreamChannel.java:249)
    at org.xnio.ssl.JsseConnectedSslStreamChannel.handleUnwrapResult(JsseConnectedSslStreamChannel.java:526)
    at org.xnio.ssl.JsseConnectedSslStreamChannel.handleHandshake(JsseConnectedSslStreamChannel.java:396)
    at org.xnio.ssl.JsseConnectedSslStreamChannel.doFlush(JsseConnectedSslStreamChannel.java:638)
    at org.xnio.ssl.JsseConnectedSslStreamChannel.flushAction(JsseConnectedSslStreamChannel.java:613)
    at org.xnio.channels.TranslatingSuspendableChannel.flush(TranslatingSuspendableChannel.java:604)
    at org.xnio.channels.FramedMessageChannel.flushAction(FramedMessageChannel.java:275)
    at org.xnio.channels.TranslatingSuspendableChannel.flush(TranslatingSuspendableChannel.java:604)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnection$RemoteWriteListener.send(RemoteConnection.java:306)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnection.send(RemoteConnection.java:124)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionHandler.sendCloseRequestBody(RemoteConnectionHandler.java:286)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionProvider$3$1.cancel(RemoteConnectionProvider.java:177)
    at org.xnio.AbstractIoFuture.cancel(AbstractIoFuture.java:306)
    at org.xnio.AbstractIoFuture.cancel(AbstractIoFuture.java:39)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionProvider.closeAction(RemoteConnectionProvider.java:236)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.spi.AbstractHandleableCloseable.closeAsync(AbstractHandleableCloseable.java:359)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.closeAction(EndpointImpl.java:204)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.spi.AbstractHandleableCloseable.closeAsync(AbstractHandleableCloseable.java:359)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.EndpointCache.release(EndpointCache.java:58)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.EndpointCache$EndpointWrapper.closeAsync(EndpointCache.java:189)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory$1.close(InitialContextFactory.java:231)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.finalize(RemoteContext.java:199)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.invokeFinalizeMethod(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Finalizer.java:101)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Finalizer.java:32)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:190)"

!ENTRY com.test.my.client.fwk 0 0 2014-11-21 15:04:50.498
!MESSAGE (Timezone is ICT.)  ;6340; org.xnio.safe-close logged : "Closing resource org.xnio.channels.FramedMessageChannel around org.xnio.ssl.JsseConnectedSslStreamChannel around TCP socket channel (NIO) <139ba40>"
```

Comment: Try add `remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_DISALLOWED_MECHANISMS=JBOSS-LOCAL-USER` in your conecction properties.

Comment: I just try with JBOSS-LOCAL_USER, but I faced other problem:DEBUG [Remoting "config-based-naming-client-endpoint" read-1] - Client received authentication rejected for mechanism DIGEST-MD5
ERROR [Remoting "config-based-naming-client-endpoint" read-1] - JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed
DEBUG [main] - Failed to connect to server remote://10.10.10.10:4447

Comment: I found the root cause because I provide wrong password. Thanks for your help.